# Is it possible to play as Knuckles in Sonic 1 on the Wii Virtual Console?

Tags: sonic-the-hedgehog

I have an original Wii. I downloaded the original Sonic Genesis games on the Wii Virtual Console: Sonic the Hedgehog 1, Sonic the Hedgehog 2, Sonic the Hedgehog 3, and Sonic & Knuckles.

As most Sonic fans know, Sonic 1 is unfortunately incompatible with Sonic and Knuckle's lock on technology. And this is true even for the virtual console as I found out. Though in 2005 I read somewhere that a Knuckles in Sonic One  version was released. Though I couldn’t find it in the Wii shop channel.

Is it possible to play as Knuckles in Sonic 1 on the Wii? Either as a mod or a purchasable downloadable game?

Answer (score 3):

**It is not possible to play as Knuckles in the Wii Virtual Console release of Sonic the Hedgehog 1.**

According to a post on [The Escapist Forums](http://www.escapistmagazine.com/forums/read/9.244264-Quick-question-on-Sonic-and-the-Virtual-Console), it *is* possible to use the Sonic & Knuckles lock-on technology with Sonic 1, 2, and 3 if if you own Sonic & Knuckles on the Wii Virtual Console. However, like the original 1991 Genesis release, this only unlocks the blue sphere mini-game in Sonic 1.

> Press the '-' button on the Wii Remote. This can be done ANY time. The game will reset and reload as what ever you chose. There are 4 options: Normal, Sonic 1, Sonic 2 and Sonic 3.
>
> Normal is just Sonic & Knuckles, and the others are Get Blue Spheres (*Sonic 1*), Knuckles in Sonic 2, and Sonic 3 & Knuckles

You can officially play as Knuckles in other later releases of Sonic 1. [He can be unlocked](https://help.sega.net/hc/en-us/articles/4474275555095-How-to-unlock-Tails-and-Knuckles) in the remastered [iOS](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/sonic-the-hedgehog-classic/id316025912?mt=8) and [Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sega.sonic1px&hl=en) ports by [Christian Whitehead](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christian_Whitehead) or the Sonic Origins collection. Alternatively there are several fan projects that let you play as Knuckles such as the [Sonic 1 decompilation](https://github.com/Rubberduckycooly/Sonic-1-2-2013-Decompilation), [Sonic 1 Forever](https://teamforeveronline.wixsite.com/home/sonic-1-forever), or [Stealth's Knuckles in Sonic 1 romhack](https://www.romhacking.net/hacks/172/).